# Formatting xlwings view output

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I am using xlwings to write a dataframe to an excel sheet. Nothing special, and all works perfectly.

```py
   xw.view(
       dataframe,
       abook.sheets.add(after = abook.sheets[-1]),
       table=True
   )
```

My issue is that the output excel sheet has filters in the top two rows, which I have to manually disable (by selecting the rows and clearning contents).

Thanks to  https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/679#issuecomment-369138719

I changed my code to the following:

```py
abook = xw.books.active
xw.view(
   dataframe,
   abook.sheets.add(after = abook.sheets[-1]),
   table=True
)
sheetname = abook.active.name
if wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilterMode == True:
      wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilterMode = False
```

which looked promising, but it didn't resolve my issue.

[image: sample sheet header]

I would appreciate any pointers, how I can have the filters turned off by default. I am using the latest xlwings on win 10, 11.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated on 14  January 2023: 
Just for completeness, using the argument `table=True` in `view` adds a table with a filter. If you would like to keep the table, but remove the filter, you can remove the filter with `ws.tables[0].show_autofilter = False`:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()

xw.view(df, table=True)
ws = xw.sheets.active

ws.tables[0].show_autofilter = False
```

Or with `api.AutoFilter(Field=[...], VisibleDropDown=False)`, whereby `Field` is a list of integers describing the concerning column numbers:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df = pd._testing.makeDataFrame()

xw.view(df, table=True)
ws = xw.sheets.active

ws.used_range.api.AutoFilter(Field=list(range(1, ws.used_range[-1].column + 1)), VisibleDropDown=False)
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. (what do you mean by ```Field:=1```). While trying to get this to work, I discovered the table flag for xw.view, which when I set to False, it wrote the dataframe into the excel sheet without the filters.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the

```py
table=False
```

parameter to the xw.view(df) method. According to the docs:

```py
table (bool, default True) – If your object is a pandas DataFrame, by default it is formatted as an Excel Table
```

Now to write a dataframe df, I call:

```py
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
xw.view(df, table=False)
```